# Sorting a list by hundreds/ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I want to sort a **list**:

```
[103, 302, 405, 204, 301, 105, 202, 303, 201, 404]
```

to produce:

```
[201, 301, 202, 302, 103, 303, 204, 404, 105, 405]
```

How could I do this?

Comment: What about tens?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to sort longer numbers is realizing you are just sorting by the reversed number.

```
sorted(L, key=lambda x: str(x)[::-1])
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) +1

Comment: by a whole minute :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by the digits in reverse order, I'd say that's one place where using a string for comparison might be condoned:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: str(x)[::-1])
```

This provides the output:

```
[201, 301, 202, 302, 103, 303, 204, 404, 105, 405]
```

Here's an [IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/JPT3ie)

Answer (score 0):

Define a lambda function to pull out the digits you want, and use it as the sort key.  For example:

```
list = [103, 302, 405, 204, 301, 105, 202, 303, 201, 404]
result = sorted(list, key=lambda x: ((x % 10), (x / 100 % 10)))
```

Basically this says sort this list using a sort key of the ones digits, then the hundreds digit.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can have numbers of length other than 3, or/and it doesn't have to be zeros in the middle:

```
def myFunc(n):
  x = ''
  while n:
    x = x + str(n % 10)
    n = (n - n % 10) // 10
  return int(x)

cars = [103, 302, 405, 204, 301, 105, 202, 303, 201, 404]

cars.sort(key=myFunc)

print(cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use quotient (`%`) and floor division (`//`) operators to define a sort key:

```
L = [103, 302, 405, 204, 301, 105, 202, 303, 201, 404]

res = sorted(L, key=lambda x: (x % 10, x // 100))

[201, 301, 202, 302, 103, 303, 204, 404, 105, 405]
```

If you can use a 3rd party library, this is more efficient with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([103, 302, 405, 204, 301, 105, 202, 303, 201, 404])

res = A[np.lexsort((A // 100, A % 10))]

array([201, 301, 202, 302, 103, 303, 204, 404, 105, 405])
```